# I have a problem in sending signal from android studio "Sending signal. PID: 12499 SIG: 9"

Tags: java, android, adb

this appears when i want to run the code. what should i do ?

```
12/04 23:33:39: Launching app
    No apk changes detected since last installation, skipping installation of C:\Users\Omara\AndroidStudioProjects\FadeingAnimation\app\build\outputs\apk\app-debug.apk
    $ adb shell am force-stop com.omar_alhjri.fadeinganimation
    $ adb shell am start -n "com.omar_alhjri.fadeinganimation/com.omar_alhjri.fadeinganimation.MainActivity_3" -a android.intent.action.MAIN -c android.intent.category.LAUNCHER
    Client not ready yet..Connected to process 12499 on device samsung-gt_i9082-410086da984a7000
    I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.view.Window$Callback.onProvideKeyboardShortcuts, referenced from method android.support.v7.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.onProvideKeyboardShortcuts
    W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve interface method 15725: Landroid/view/Window$Callback;.onProvideKeyboardShortcuts (Ljava/util/List;Landroid/view/Menu;I)V
    D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x72 at 0x0002
    W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to find class referenced in signature (Landroid/view/SearchEvent;)
    I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.view.Window$Callback.onSearchRequested, referenced from method android.support.v7.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.onSearchRequested
    W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve interface method 15727: Landroid/view/Window$Callback;.onSearchRequested (Landroid/view/SearchEvent;)Z
    D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x72 at 0x0002
    I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.view.Window$Callback.onWindowStartingActionMode, referenced from method android.support.v7.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.onWindowStartingActionMode
    W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve interface method 15731: Landroid/view/Window$Callback;.onWindowStartingActionMode (Landroid/view/ActionMode$Callback;I)Landroid/view/ActionMode;
    D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x72 at 0x0002
    I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.content.res.TypedArray.getChangingConfigurations, referenced from method android.support.v7.widget.TintTypedArray.getChangingConfigurations
    W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 453: Landroid/content/res/TypedArray;.getChangingConfigurations ()I
    D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0002
    I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.content.res.TypedArray.getType, referenced from method android.support.v7.widget.TintTypedArray.getType
    W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 475: Landroid/content/res/TypedArray;.getType (I)I
    D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0008
    I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.widget.FrameLayout.startActionModeForChild, referenced from method android.support.v7.widget.ActionBarContainer.startActionModeForChild
    W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 16158: Landroid/widget/FrameLayout;.startActionModeForChild (Landroid/view/View;Landroid/view/ActionMode$Callback;I)Landroid/view/ActionMode;
    D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6f at 0x0002
    I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.content.Context.getColorStateList, referenced from method android.support.v7.content.res.AppCompatResources.getColorStateList
    W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 268: Landroid/content/Context;.getColorStateList (I)Landroid/content/res/ColorStateList;
    D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0006
    I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable, referenced from method android.support.v7.widget.ResourcesWrapper.getDrawable
    W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 416: Landroid/content/res/Resources;.getDrawable (ILandroid/content/res/Resources$Theme;)Landroid/graphics/drawable/Drawable;
    D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0002
    I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.content.res.Resources.getDrawableForDensity, referenced from method android.support.v7.widget.ResourcesWrapper.getDrawableForDensity
    W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 418: Landroid/content/res/Resources;.getDrawableForDensity (IILandroid/content/res/Resources$Theme;)Landroid/graphics/drawable/Drawable;
    D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0002
    E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.graphics.drawable.RippleDrawable', referenced from method android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageHelper.hasOverlappingRendering
    W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve instanceof 136 (Landroid/graphics/drawable/RippleDrawable;) in Landroid/support/v7/widget/AppCompatImageHelper;
    D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x20 at 0x000c
    D/dalvikvm: GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 193K, 14% free 8668K/10016K, paused 17ms, total 17ms
    I/dalvikvm-heap: Grow heap (frag case) to 26.068MB for 17280016-byte allocation
    D/dalvikvm: GC_FOR_ALLOC freed <1K, 6% free 25543K/26892K, paused 15ms, total 15ms
    E/dalvikvm: adjustAdaptiveCoef max=4194304, min=1048576, ut=568
    D/dalvikvm: GC_CONCURRENT freed 5K, 6% free 25537K/26892K, paused 3ms+1ms, total 19ms
    E/dalvikvm: adjustAdaptiveCoef max=6291456, min=1572864, ut=368
    D/dalvikvm: GC_FOR_ALLOC freed <1K, 6% free 25537K/26892K, paused 13ms, total 14ms
    I/dalvikvm-heap: Forcing collection of SoftReferences for 38880016-byte allocation
    E/dalvikvm: adjustAdaptiveCoef max=8388608, min=2097152, ut=256
    D/dalvikvm: GC_BEFORE_OOM freed 9K, 6% free 25527K/26892K, paused 25ms, total 25ms
    E/dalvikvm-heap: Out of memory on a 38880016-byte allocation.
    I/dalvikvm: "main" prio=5 tid=1 RUNNABLE
    I/dalvikvm:   | group="main" sCount=0 dsCount=0 obj=0x410e59a0 self=0x40fbd390
    I/dalvikvm:   | sysTid=12499 nice=-19 sched=0/0 cgrp=apps handle=1075193308
    I/dalvikvm:   | state=R schedstat=( 0 0 0 ) utm=34 stm=9 core=1
    I/dalvikvm:     at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeAsset(Native Method)
    I/dalvikvm:     at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:596)
    I/dalvikvm:     at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(BitmapFactory.java:444)
    I/dalvikvm:     at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromResourceStream(Drawable.java:817)
    I/dalvikvm:     at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:2854)
    I/dalvikvm:     at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable(Resources.java:1521)
    I/dalvikvm:     at android.support.v7.widget.ResourcesWrapper.getDrawable(ResourcesWrapper.java:128)
    I/dalvikvm:     at android.support.v7.widget.TintResources.getDrawable(TintResources.java:45)
    I/dalvikvm:     at android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat.getDrawable(ContextCompat.java:346)
    I/dalvikvm:     at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.getDrawable(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:197)
    I/dalvikvm:     at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.getDrawable(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:185)
    I/dalvikvm:     at android.support.v7.content.res.AppCompatResources.getDrawable(AppCompatResources.java:100)
    I/dalvikvm:     at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageHelper.loadFromAttributes(AppCompatImageHelper.java:50)
    I/dalvikvm:     at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView.<init>(AppCompatImageView.java:63)
    I/dalvikvm:     at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView.<init>(AppCompatImageView.java:53)
    I/dalvikvm:     at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater.createView(AppCompatViewInflater.java:106)
    I/dalvikvm:     at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.createView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:1013)
    I/dalvikvm:     at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.onCreateView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:1072)
    I/dalvikvm:     at android.support.v4.view.LayoutInflaterCompatHC$FactoryWrapperHC.onCreateView(LayoutInflaterCompatHC.java:44)
    I/dalvikvm:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:681)
    I/dalvikvm:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:752)
    I/dalvikvm:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:495)
    I/dalvikvm:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
    I/dalvikvm:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353)
    I/dalvikvm:     at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:284)
    I/dalvikvm:     at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140)
    I/dalvikvm:     at com.omar_alhjri.fadeinganimation.MainActivity_3.onCreate(MainActivity_3.java:24)
    I/dalvikvm:     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5283)
    I/dalvikvm:     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1097)
    I/dalvikvm:     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2209)
    I/dalvikvm:     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2299)
    I/dalvikvm:     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:150)
    I/dalvikvm:     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1280)
    I/dalvikvm:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    I/dalvikvm:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
    I/dalvikvm:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5283)
    I/dalvikvm:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    I/dalvikvm:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
    I/dalvikvm:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1102)
    I/dalvikvm:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:869)
    I/dalvikvm:     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
    D/skia: --- allocation failed for scaled bitmap
    D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
    W/dalvikvm: threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x410e4930)
    E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                      java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
                          at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeAsset(Native Method)
                          at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:596)
                          at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(BitmapFactory.java:444)
                          at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromResourceStream(Drawable.java:817)
                          at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:2854)
                          at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable(Resources.java:1521)
                          at android.support.v7.widget.ResourcesWrapper.getDrawable(ResourcesWrapper.java:128)
                          at android.support.v7.widget.TintResources.getDrawable(TintResources.java:45)
                          at android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat.getDrawable(ContextCompat.java:346)
                          at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.getDrawable(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:197)
                          at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.getDrawable(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:185)
                          at android.support.v7.content.res.AppCompatResources.getDrawable(AppCompatResources.java:100)
                          at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageHelper.loadFromAttributes(AppCompatImageHelper.java:50)
                          at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView.<init>(AppCompatImageView.java:63)
                          at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView.<init>(AppCompatImageView.java:53)
                          at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater.createView(AppCompatViewInflater.java:106)
                          at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.createView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:1013)
                          at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.onCreateView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:1072)
                          at android.support.v4.view.LayoutInflaterCompatHC$FactoryWrapperHC.onCreateView(LayoutInflaterCompatHC.java:44)
                          at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:681)
                          at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:752)
                          at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:495)
                          at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
                          at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353)
                          at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:284)
                          at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140)
                          at com.omar_alhjri.fadeinganimation.MainActivity_3.onCreate(MainActivity_3.java:24)
                          at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5283)
                          at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1097)
                          at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2209)
                          at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2299)
                          at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:150)
                          at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1280)
                          at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
                          at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
                          at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5283)
                          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
                          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1102)
                          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:869)
                          at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
    I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 12499 SIG: 9
    Application terminated.
```

Comment: this is not a question, this is just a stacktrace...

Comment: If you could give some context...  Just posting a stack trace is not helpful at all.

Comment: It says _Out of memory_ clear enough.